# Cookie Code not removing opened element of cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
var openClose = $('.openClose');
openClose.on('click', function() {
   var cook = ReadCookie('slideHide'),
       miniParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content'),
       miniDisp = miniParent.css('display');
     if (miniDisp ==="block") {
         KillCookie('slideHide');
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content').slideUp();
   var slide = cook + "," + "#"+$(this)
                         .parent()
                         .parent()
                         .parent()
                         .parent().attr("id") +
                         " #"+$(this).parent()
                         .parent().parent().attr("id");
            SetCookie('slideHide', slide, 100);
        } 
        else
        {
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content').slideDown();
       var newCookie=[];
  var a= $('.module').children('.main-content').filter(":hidden");
       for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
         var d = $(a[i++]);
        var c = "#"+d.parent('.module').attr('id');
       }
       newCookie= c;
       console.log(newCookie);
               KillCookie('slideHide');
               SetCookie('slideHide',d, 100);
        }
  });
```

These are my cookie functions:

```
  function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
     var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
      if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
       expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
       document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
        + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString(),';path = /';
       }

  function KillCookie(cookieName) {
      SetCookie(cookieName,"", - 1);
    }

   function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
      var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
      var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName+"=");
     if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
         var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind);
         if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
         return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
      }
```

Setting the cookie to make it slideUp and stay hidden works, but when I try to open it, it slidesDown, then I refresh the page it doesn't stay open like it should.

To sort of get the picture - http://jsfiddle.net/zRT9u/

If you need to know more please ask me I am willing to provide more!

I edited the javascript it almost works but I am not getting all the objects that I need

NEW EDIT- Tried the `$.map()` function but when I open one, and refresh all of them are now open?

```
  else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content').slideDown();
KillCookie('slideHide');
    var newCookie=[];
    var a= $('.module').children('.main-content').filter(":hidden");
    var c = $.map(a,function(n,i){
      return $(n).parent().attr('id');
    });
    newCookie= c;
    SetCookie('slideHide',newCookie, 100);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using `$.map` and `.join()`

```
var openClose = $('.openClose');
  openClose.on('click', function() {
  var cook = ReadCookie('slideHide'),
      miniParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content'),
      miniDisp = miniParent.css('display');
         if (miniDisp ==="block") {
            KillCookie('slideHide');
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content').slideUp();
       var slide = cook+","+ "#"+$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
         SetCookie('slideHide', slide, 100);
        } else {
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.main-content').slideDown();
     KillCookie('slideHide');
    var newCookie=[],
    a= $('.module').children('.main-content').filter(":hidden"),
    c = $.map(a,function(n,i){
    return "#"+$(n).parent().attr('id');
 });
 newCookie= c.join(',');
  SetCookie('slideHide',newCookie, 100);
  }
});
```

By creating a "global" array and then using the `$.map` function as well as adding `"#"+` to the map function I was able to get the actual ID names. Then I set `newCookie` to `c.join(',')`  and everything works perfectly after that!